# Java - for arrays, removing evens

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to create a method that will remove the even integers of an array. The method creates a new array with just the evens. So far I have the evens removed, and in the front of the new array, however there are 0's in place of the evens I removed and I'm trying to get rid of them. Here is the method:

```
public int[] change(int[] in) {

      int count=0;
      int[] out= new int[in.length];
      for(int i=0; i<in.length;i++){

           if(in[i] % 2 !=0){
                out[count]=in[i];
                count++;

           }

           else{

           }

      }

      return out;
   }
}
```

Help! I know I'm just missing one detail but I can't catch it.

Comment: There is no `else{}`.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Okay, go through the `in` array twice. In the first `forloop` do a count to see how large the `out` array should be. In the second loop, use the loop you currently have without the `else{}`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you have your `out` array created with the length of your `in` array. That's why you have the zero. You `out` array will be shorter than you `in` array except when the `in` array contains all odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here is one. First, loop through `in` to see how many will be noneven. This number will be the length of `out`. Then use the same code you have to populate out.

```
public int [] change(int[] in)
{
    int outLength = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
    {
        if(in[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            outLength++;
        }
    }

    int[] out = new int[outLength];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
    {
        if(in[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            out[counter] = in[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `int[]` array, use a `List<Integer>`. You cannot remove any elements from a *"normal"* array, only edit them.

```
// If you already know the size of your array, you may want to use this syntax.
final List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
     // The final modifier is not necessary - you can just ignore it if you want.
     final int value = in[i];
     if (value % 2 != 0) {
         list.add(value);
         count++;
     }
}
```

You can convert a `List<Integer>` into an `int[]` array via the `list.toArray(new Integer[0]);` operation.

```
final int[] out = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

If the code mentioned above doesn't work, you are probably using an earlier Version of the JDK. To resolve this issue, simply swap out the `0` with the `list.size()` method.

```
final int[] out = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

So what you essentially want is to have a second array containing just even numbers you can do this by first counting even numbers in given array and then declaring new array with size of number of even numbers and then populate them.